# Do I need to install Azure SDK On headless Build Server?

Tags: azure, msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy, azure-sdk-.net

When running the same build command on my machine vs our TeamCity Build Server, my machine deploys our VS2012 Web Site to azure (Web Sites), yet the Build Machine doesn't.

- No errors are produced on the build server.
- The build server creates the deployment package, but simply doesn't publish.

What surely must be a clue, is that the output on the build server is very different with the same command (main sections only - I've cut lots out)...

**Build Server (which does not physically publish)**

1. PiplelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder:
2. Package:
3. GenerateMsdeploymanifestFiles:
4. PackageUsingManifest:
5. GenerateSampleDeployScript:
6. PipelineDeployPhase:
7. Build Succeeded..

**My machine Build Server (which does physically publish)**

1. PipelineCopyAllFilesToOneFolderForMsDeploy:
2. GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles:
3. MSDeployPublish: ** This is missing when run on the server - I'm guessing this is key!
4. PipelineDeployPhase:
5. Build Succeeded..

**We do not have VS2012 Installed on the build server, but should we install the DSK on the server? Do the output differences indicate a lack of the SDK??**

Comment: Try this website.                 http://www.jayway.com/2011/03/20/configuring-automatic-deployment-of-a-windows-azure-application-using-teamcity/

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see if you have set the 'Target' to publish?

[image: Target in TeamCity - Build step]

Comment: Hi Hari, I don't have that option as I'm simply using the Runner Type of "Command Line" and therefore do not get that option. That was I know that I'm using the same command in each case. I've had to park this for the moment as I couldn't get it to work but am visiting again in a couple of weeks so will try this then. Thanks for the hint - I'll try that.